# Having trouble pinpointing this error wrong argument listp 1

Tags: debugging

I'm having trouble finding where the problem here is exactly. The result I'd like returned is a string that looks like

```
1. (n,adj-no) occupation
2. business
```

My function is here and it looks like something is supposed to be a list but isn't.

```
(defun japanese-get-definition (dictentry)
  "Get a definition from a dictionary entry."
  (let* (index 1)
    (save-match-data
      (and (string-match "/\\(.*?\\)$" dictentry)
           (setq definitions (split-string (match-string 1 dictentry) "/" t))
           (dolist (definition definitions)
             (setq definition (concat (int-to-string index) ". " definition))
             (setq index (+ index 1)))
           (mapconcat 'identity
                      definitions
                      "\n"))
      )
    )
  )
(japanese-get-definition "職業 [しょくぎょう] /(n,adj-no) occupation/business/")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for `let*`.

Use `(let* ((index 1))...)` to bind variable `index` to the value `1`.

Use `C-h f let* RET` to see a description of `let*`.  Use `C-h S let* RET` to read more about it in the manual.

And always read (and report) the exact error message that you get. It's meant to help you.  If you get a debugger backtrace, report that.

You can customize option `debug-on-error` to `t` to enter the debugger automatically when an error occurs. Use `C-h S debug-on-error` to read about this in the manual.

In this case, the error message told you that Emacs was expecting a list (tested by predicate `listp`), and instead it received the number `1`. That is a hint that you are using the wrong syntax.

After `let*` comes a list of bindings or implicit bindings (to `nil`).  You have a list, whose first element is the symbol `index`. This is interpreted as an implicit binding of variable `index` to the value `nil`. The second element of your list is the number `1`, which is neither a symbol (an implicit binding to `nil` of the symbol as a variable) nor a list (an explicit binding of a symbol to an explicit value).

Comment: That's now working, I also included `(definitions)` into the let* and the function no longer throws an error but now it seems that the return value is nil. instead of what I hoped which was the result of mapconcat

Comment: If you have another question then please ask it separately. You don't show your fixed version so it is anyway difficult to guess why you are getting `nil` (or even whether you are really getting `nil`). `save-match-data` returns the result of its last sexp, and `mapconcat` returns the result of concatenating its sequence elements.

Comment: new question please advise :) http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/dolist-not-modifying-the-list
I saw your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202330/process-list-modifying-elements-in-elisp but I'm not sure why mine isn't working as intended