# Dolist not modifying the list

Tags: elisp, list

I'm trying to prepend each substring of `split-string` with numbering (1.,2.,3.,..) then return all the substrings concatenated with a newline

```
(defun japanese-get-definition (dictentry)
  "Get a definition from a dictionary entry."
  (let* ((index 1)
         (definitions))
    (save-match-data
      (and (string-match "/\\(.*?\\)$" dictentry)
           (setq definitions (split-string (match-string 1 dictentry) "/" t))
           (dolist (definition definitions)
             (setq definition (concat (int-to-string index) ". " definition))
             (setq index (+ index 1)))
           (mapconcat 'identity
                      definitions
                      "\n"))
      )
    )
  )

(japanese-get-definition "職業 [しょくぎょう] /(n,adj-no) occupation/business/")
```

So the result would looks like

```
1. (n,adj-no) occupation
2. business
```

Currently though the function is returning nil. Is dolist the right function to use? This would probably be very easy if I just use a new list, but I'm hoping to use learn the best way to do this (which I *think* (could be wrong) is modifying the existing list so less memory is used)

Comment: Emacs Lisp is not a language where memory usage should be your primary concern.  Copying lists is totally fine, and treating lists as immutable helps you write better code.

Comment: @lunaryorn That's fine I may switch to copying to a list but I am still extremely curious as to why mapconcat returns nil for the above.

Comment: It's dolist which returns nil here, but that's documented behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `dolist` can have no effect on `definitions`. If you remove it from your function you will see that you get a result (but not exactly what you wanted). The `mapconcat` is evaluated and does not return `nil`.
2. The result of `(setq definitions (split-string (match-string 1 dictentry) "/" t))` in your test example is `("(n,adj-no) occupation" "business")`.
3. The `mapconcat` applied to that would give `"(n,adj-no) occupation\nbusiness"`
4. `dolist` returns `nil`, so the `mapconcat` is never evaluated.
5. If you wrap your `dolist` with `(progn ... t)` then the `mapconcat` will be evaluated.

But your main problem is thinking that `dolist` modifies the original list. As explained in the [post you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209218/729907) in your other question, you can use `dolist` to modify individual elements of the list but not the list itself.

For example, if the list had particular strings or lists as its elements, you could modify those individual objects.  (The individual elements of the list must of course be modifiable, for you to modify them. You cannot modify numbers, for example.)

But in your case you want to modify the list itself.  You want to replace a given element with a completely different value -- that is, replace it ***in the list***.  That's not the same as modifying an element (which changes the value globally).  You cannot do that with `dolist`.

Here's one quick, ugly-hacky way to do what you want.  It doesn't change your code much.  It just replaces the `dolist` by some code that modifies `definitions`.

```el
(defun japanese-get-definition (dictentry)
  "Get a definition from a dictionary entry."
  (let* ((index 1)
         (definitions))
    (save-match-data
      (and (string-match "/\\(.*?\\)$" dictentry)
           (setq definitions (split-string (match-string 1 dictentry) "/" t))
           (let ((defs  definitions))
             (while defs
               (setcar defs (concat (int-to-string index) ". " (car defs)))
               (setq index  (1+ index)
                     defs   (cdr defs)))
             t)
           (mapconcat 'identity definitions "\n")))))
```

This is slightly simpler, but still not very pretty:

```el
(defun japanese-get-definition (dictentry)
  "Get a definition from a dictionary entry."
  (let* ((index       1)
         (definitions ()))
    (save-match-data
      (when (string-match "/\\(.*?\\)$" dictentry)
        (setq definitions  (split-string (match-string 1 dictentry) "/" t))
        (let ((defs  definitions))
          (while defs
            (setcar defs (concat (int-to-string index) ". " (car defs)))
            (setq index  (1+ index)
                  defs   (cdr defs))))
        (mapconcat 'identity definitions "\n")))))
```

Comment: The explanation on each function is much appreciated! Someone on the irc channel also gave a cleaner solution (which I posted in a separate answer) that I liked a lot so I also answered the question to share it with others!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Drew for the explanation on what I was doing wrong. Another way to approach the problem (thanks tali713) is with a lambda in mapconcat

```
(defun japanese-get-definition (dictentry)
  "Get a definition from a dictionary entry."
  (let ((index 0))
    (mapconcat (lambda (str) (format "%s. %s" (incf index) str))
               (split-string dictentry "/" t)
               "\n")))
```

for a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was trying to keep close to your original code and speak about `dolist` and the question of what was returning `nil`. This is the right way to do it: let `mapconcat` do everything.